# Define logback shutdown hook in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I am using AsyncAppender in spring-boot (1.5.3.RELEASE) application.

**logback.xml**

```
<appender name="FILE_ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>5000</queueSize>
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</appender>
```

As per logback documentation,

> Upon application shutdown or redeploy, AsyncAppender must be stopped
>   in order to stop and reclaim the worker thread and to flush the
>   logging events from the queue.

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Further it says:

> In order to avoid interrupting the worker thread under these
>   conditions, a shutdown hook can be inserted to the JVM runtime that
>   stops the LoggerContext properly after JVM shutdown has been initiated

I want to know how to stop AsyncAppender in Spring Boot application. At which place in Spring Boot, should I define shutdown hook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the `<shutdownHook/>` instruction to your `logback.xml`. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>

    <appender name="FILE_ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>5000</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <!-- the rest of your logback config -->

</configuration>
```

With this in place you'll notice the following log message is emitted when Logback is configuring itself:

> INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ShutdownHookAction - About to instantiate shutdown hook of type [ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook]

Answer (score 6):

You need not define the shutdown hook explicitly since version `1.1.10` of logback. Version `1.1.10` onwards, logback takes care of stopping the current logback-classic context (and all the appenders) when the web-app is stopped or reloaded. Try updating your logback version and check once.

Here's the updated doc: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#webShutdownHook

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem but with version 1.1.6 of logback and spring-boot 1.5.4.
The solution for me was to add :

```
logging.register-shutdown-hook=true
```

to the application.properties file for inviting

`org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem` to stop the LoggerContext on ApplicationContext.close invocation.